# AS3 stageWebView drawViewPortToBitmapData listen to draw Completed

Tags: actionscript-3, air

Just wondering if there a listener you can add to check if the drawViewPortToBitmapData have been completed? I am try to capture the PDF which loaded on the screen its quite large bitmap.

plus drawViewPortToBitmapData somehow doesn't work on the pc, but works fine on the tablet. any idea?

```
var screenBD:BitmapData = new BitmapData(
    _swv.viewPort.width,
    _swv.viewPort.height,
    true, 0xFFFFFF
);

_swv.drawViewPortToBitmapData(screenBD);
var screen:Bitmap = new Bitmap(screenBD);
screen.y = 40;
```

Cheers
Bill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no Complete listener for drawViewPortToBitmapData() you would have to go under the hood and write it yourself!
But you should be able to add it after you created the Bitmap from it!

```
...
var screen:Bitmap = new Bitmap(screenBD);
addChild(screen);
```

drawViewPortToBitmapData() is AIR only, so running the swf on the Pc wont work, you would have to publish for Desktop